# R,G,B in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you output every rgb color with javascript at the same time easily and quickly ?
I have tried loops and nested loops but they were not what I needed.

```
var r, g, b;
for (r = o,r < 255,r++)
    console.log(r);

for (g = 0,g < 255,g++)
    console.log(g);

for (b = 0,b < 255,b++)
    console.log(b);
```

Comment: What kind of output are you expecting, exactly? Could you provide a sample output, even if incomplete?

Comment: you need to nest all the loop and are you aware that you will print 16581375 values?

Comment: Yes , I am aware .

Comment: Well the kind of output I'm expecting is to fully organise all colors with colors not just words with rgb and to quickly find a color for designing like with google-fu.

Answer (score 1):

There are 256*256*256 or 16 million combinations in the 24 bit R,G,B color space.  A Simple loop over all of them would be:

```
for(var r = 0; r < 256; r++) {
    for(var g = 0; g < 256; g++){
        for(var b = 0; b < 256; b++){
            console.log("("+r+","+g+","+b+")")
        }
    }
}
```

This will not be fast and at some point the browser will stop printing to the console.

Answer (score 1):

**First correction:** Do a triple nested `for loop` so you can get all the combinations. (256 * 256 * 256)

**Second correction:** semicolons instead of commas inside `for loop` brackets. `for (___; ____; ___)`.

**Third correction** The upper bound value of each `for loop` should be `256` instead of `255`. That's because when you use `< 255`, the variable will never take value equal to `255`, instead it will take maximum value 254. Therefore, use `256` to make it go upto `255`. (Maximum intensity count of each color channel).

```
var r, g, b;
for(r = 0; r < 256; r++) {
    for(g = 0; g < 256; g++) {
        for(b = 0; b < 256; b++) {
            console.log(r + " " + g + " " + b);
        }
    }
}
```